# How to auto adjust the height of list row in edit mode?

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-list

I have a list. When I click the show button in any of rows, the long text appears and the height of row auto gets taller enough to show all of the long text.

However, when the list is in "edit" mode, the height of row can't auto get taller enough to show all of the long text. The long text is truncated. I have to push the list to the top manually and release, then the height of row auto gets taller and the long text can be completely displayed again. Is there any way to achieve the "auto" adjustment effect just the same as the "non-edit" mode?

```
struct ListEditTest: View {
    @State private var selects: Set<Int> = []
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            EditButton()
            List(selection: $selects){
                ForEach(1..<5){
                    ItemInList(num: $0)
                }
            }
            .listStyle(PlainListStyle())
        }
    }
}
struct ItemInList: View{
    let num: Int
    @State private var showDetail = false
    var body: some View{
        HStack{
            Text("NO.\(num)")
            Text("HelloWorld")
            if showDetail{
                Text("TooManyWordsTooManyWordsTooManyWordsTooManyWordsTooManyWordsTooManyWordsTooManyWordsTooManyWords")
                Button {
                    showDetail.toggle()
                } label: {
                    Text("Hide")
                }
            }else{
                Button {
                    showDetail.toggle()
                } label: {
                    Text("Show")
                }
            }
        }
        .buttonStyle(BorderlessButtonStyle())
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm afraid I can't indicate  the exact height of the long text needed. When I click the same "show" button, it works well in non-edit mode but not in edit mode. What leads to the difference? It seems like to need some refresh work in edit mode.

Comment: Ok, it looks like they just copy current row content into own temporary edit view which preserve current layout and not changeable. This does not look like a bug, rather as intended behavior, so I'd recommend just disable Show/Hide button for edit mode.

Comment: Thank you. I wish it is just a bug, not an intended behavior.